# Solve the following for $D$: $ABDB^{-1} = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

[image]

So, here's what I know, 'I' is typically:

\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}

But, from that I really have no idea where to go with this question. I know basic matrix inversion rules, but I am unsure how to solve.

Comment: This is just about multiplying by $A, B, A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ on both side, to isolate D. No calculus is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** How would you solve this equation for $d$?

$$abdc=1$$ assuming $a,b,c \neq 0$. Let's also assume that $a,b,c,d$ do not commute. Secondly, the $I$ you mentioned above is often denoted $I_3$, as it is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. You are working with $I_n$, which has a diagonal containing $n$ $1$'s.

Comment: Would it be something along the lines of:

d = "$a^-1 b^-1 c^-1$"  ?

Comment: @mezzani almost, it should be $d = b^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}$

Comment: Ah, so in my original, it would change mean:

$d = b^{-1}a^{-1}b$ ?

the $(b^{-1})^{-1} = b$ is correct?

Comment: Correct, since you can "substitute" $1 \equiv I_n$, $d \equiv D$,  $a \equiv A$, $b \equiv B$ and $c \equiv B^{-1}$

Answer (score -1):

$ ABDB^{-1} = I \quad\leadsto\quad D = B^{-1}A^{-1}IB $

Comment: Leaving the identity matrix in $B^{-1}A^{-1}IB$ is redundant, but the answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks Graydad, it was just for reference, to see the order of the operations